# Is it possible to clear the cache of a specific url with NGINX?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am using NGINX as a reverse server, but I have a problem when making changes to a page of my website, the changes are not seen until I clean the entire NGINX cache, causing it to clean my entire site and not just in the URL where I am working.

So I would like to know if it is possible to only clear the cache of a specific URL.

I have configured the dynamic content part but the page load exceeds 600ms and when it is only static content it loads in 200ms.

I used this command line in my terminal but it didn't work either

```
grep -lr 'https://example.com/blog/name-of-blog.php$' /var/cache/nginx/*
```

Also I already tried to configure from the .htaccess file and it has not gone as I expected.

I hope you can help me.